# Solution for a set of non-linear equations

Tags: matlab, system, non-linear

I am trying to solve the following equations for \$\delta\$ and \$K\$.

[image: equations]

I have tried Matlab function `fsolve`, but unsuccessfully. I also tried Wolfram Alpha and, again, no success. Matlab returns a value of \$0\$ for both, but I know their values. Can anyone help me with this? The correct values are \$\delta = 1.8\$ and \$K = 1.098\$.

---

### UPDATE

To solve these equations I used the least squares method, which enables me to solve sets of equations that have more equations than incognitas that are not linearly dependent.

I used Matlab to solve doing a function with a set of equations

```
function F = equations(x)

F(1) = (x(1)-x(2)+0.004);
F(2) = (-1000*x(1)- 3000*x(2)+ 2000*x(3)+ 8);
F(3) = (1000*x(1) + 1000*x(2)- 2000*x(3)- 12);
```

Then I created a code that allows me to use the equations together with the "*lsqnonlin*" function that provides the solution of the equations.

```
%% Code to solve the equations

clc
clear all
format long
fun = @equations;


options = optimoptions('lsqnonlin','Display','iter', 'Algorithm',...
'levenberg-marquardt','MaxIterations',1500,'MaxFunctionEvaluations',15000,...
'FunctionTolerance',1e-20,'StepTolerance',1e-20,'UseParallel',false);

% Initial Guess
x0 = [0;0;0];

x = lsqnonlin(fun,x0,[],[],options)
```

Comment: What set of equations? Anyway, I don't think this is the right place for equation solving.

Comment: I forgot to upload the equations, take a look again please

Comment: Three equations with two unknowns probably doesn't have a solution.

Comment: Graph them and see if they intersect at one point. I agree with @ThePhoton.

Comment: @Transistor I afraid it may fill an area in coordinate space, not just a single line or curve.

Comment: Based on @ThePhoton comment, I looked and found this on a physics forum... maybe this will help: "If there are three equations in two unknowns there are basically two possibilities - either they are inconsistent, or one is redundant. Solve any two equations and put results into third - if it is satsified, equation was redundant, if not - it was inconsistent."

Reference https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/three-equations-two-unknowns.426629/

Comment: And if there's a redundant equation, a numerical solver will have trouble recognizing it due to floating point precision limitations.

Comment: I can use the first two equations only

Comment: I got it using least-square method. Thank you guys

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an Algebra question asking for how to solve an equation. There is no obvious or expressed link with electrical engineering.

Answer (score 1):

No problem. If a solution exists, you find it manually assuming you have precise enough calculator.

The 3rd equation has D in a place which is redundant. The only effective variable is K. Multiply with the denominator and you have a simple linear equation for K. Solve K.

Insert K to the 1st and 2nd equation. Both can be reduced to same form A^D=B where A and B are numerical values. You find D as logarithm D=ln(B)/ln(A)

If both equations give the same D you have a solution.

BTW the problem is not well defined. If there's more equations than there are variables, you should define

- how much you allow the left sides be different than zero and
- what is the criteria for the best solution, if there were a set of possible (K,D) pairs which satisfy the max differece to zero declaration.